# jQuery reference to self in custom function initialize

Tags: jquery, function, reference, this, self

another challenge - this is more for cleaner looking code than a "how do I". Here's the idea.

```
<section id="projector" data-start-at="7">....</section>
```

in JS

```
$('#projector').projector_slider({'startFrom' : parseInt( REF TO DATA-START-AT )});
```

I am calling a custom function on a HTML element. Simple. The function has an option called "startFrom" indicated by an INT. The INT is stored in an attribute attached to the HTML element. What I want is to NOT have to find `$('#projector')` in the DOM again.

Is there a way I can get a reference to the Projector inside the function call - something like `$(this).attr('data-start-at)`?

Obv I can solve this by looking up the element again and accessing it directly, Im asking the question in the hopes of learning a new 'this' reference trick while cleaning up my JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. You should save `$('#projector')` in a var and use it:

```javascript
var projector = $('#projector');

projector.projector_slider({
    startFrom: parseInt(projector.data('start-at')),
});
```

Notice that I use [`.data()`][data] instead of `.attr('data-*')`. The `data()` function is created by jQuery and is a smart way to interact with `data-*` attributes. For instance, if you have `data-first=true` and use `.data('first')` you will get a boolean 'true' and if you have `data-children="['foo', 'bar']"` you will get an object if you use `.data('children')`.

Comment: Whaaa, had no idea bout .data(). A tip is a tip, thank you sir.